# multiple parameters friendly URL rewriteRule with dash instead of slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need help on rewriteRule for multiple parameters as follow:

```
sitename.com/profile/index.php?t=value1&a=value2
```

to become

```
sitename.com/profile/value1-value2
```

I tried this code but not solved.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1&id2=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1&id2=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-$2 [NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1-$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added `php` tag you can do this, put .htaccess file in profile directory

**HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_]+)$ index.php?t=$1
```

**PHP**

```
$var =  $_GET['t']; 
$var1 = explode("-", $var);
echo $t = $var1[0];
echo $a = $var1[1];
```